MIP SDK error: RHEL8 - MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File) failing with Missing .so files
When trying to utilize the MIP File SDK on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 with calling MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File), initially received an issue with missing libdl.so, solved this with linking to libdl.so.2 to libdl.so.
Now receive the following exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): LoadLibrary failed with error code 0 for: [/opt/app-root/libmip_dotnet.so]
2024-10-09 22:26:21          at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.SafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String dllToLoad)
2024-10-09 22:26:21          at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls(String dllFolder, String dllName, String[] dllDependencies)
2024-10-09 22:26:21          at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize(MipComponent mipComponent, String path)

the C++ zip for RHEL does not come with this .so file and I've no clue where to get it.
